# Nested flatten in IF statement; re-keying in multi layer flatten

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, ansi-sql

Current Query:

```
with
report as (

  select * from Report_Data
  where type = 'pnl'
  and (created_at > '2020-01-01' or updated_at > '2020-01-01')

    ),
flattened as (

    select 
        report.company_ID as "CID",
        report.type,
        report.from_date as "Report_Date",
        f.*
        --f.value:"title"




    from report,
      lateral flatten(input =>prepared:profitAndLoss:report:sections) f
      --,lateral flatten(input =>f.value)f1

)
select * from flattened where CID = 908 limit 100;
```

Current Output for f:

```
[
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Product Sales",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 19889.16,
            "value": "19,889"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 56181.94,
            "value": "56,182"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Credits from Vendors",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 38,
            "value": "38"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 47.16,
            "value": "47"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Sales - PayPal",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 275,
            "value": "275"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Sales Returns and Allowances",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": -379.28,
            "value": "(379)"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": -941.78,
            "value": "(942)"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Revenue",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": 19547.88,
          "value": "19,548"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": 55562.32,
          "value": "55,562"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Revenue"
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Product Costs",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 9857.22,
            "value": "9,857"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 31907.32,
            "value": "31,907"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Supplies",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 109.92,
            "value": "110"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Cost of Sales",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": 9857.22,
          "value": "9,857"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": 32017.24,
          "value": "32,017"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Less Cost of Sales"
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": true,
        "name": "Gross Profit",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 9690.66,
            "value": "9,691"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 23545.08,
            "value": "23,545"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "name": "",
      "values": []
    },
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Advertising & Marketing",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 100,
            "value": "100"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 100,
            "value": "100"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Advertising Expenses",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 22,
            "value": "22"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 689,
            "value": "689"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Bank Fees",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 53,
            "value": "53"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 53,
            "value": "53"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Business Telephone and Internet",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 10.08,
            "value": "10"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 30.24,
            "value": "30"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Charitable Contributions",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": -81.89,
            "value": "(82)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Computer and Software Expense",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 20,
            "value": "20"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 20,
            "value": "20"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Dues and Subscriptions",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0.99,
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 135.99,
            "value": "136"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Fees and Licenses",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 50,
            "value": "50"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Insurance Expense - General Liability",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 101.6,
            "value": "102"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 304.8,
            "value": "305"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Legal & Professional",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 200,
            "value": "200"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 600,
            "value": "600"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Merchant Account Fees",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 444.91,
            "value": "445"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 1221.71,
            "value": "1,222"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Office Expenses",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 169.66,
            "value": "170"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 988.42,
            "value": "988"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Payroll Processing Fee",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 0.45,
            "value": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Rent",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 1500,
            "value": "1,500"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 6000,
            "value": "6,000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Taxes",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 3000,
            "value": "3,000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Travel",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 194.35,
            "value": "194"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Utilities",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 559.59,
            "value": "560"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 1769.63,
            "value": "1,770"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Operating Expenses",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": 3181.83,
          "value": "3,182"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": 15075.7,
          "value": "15,076"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Operating Expenses"
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Operating Income / (Loss)",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 6508.83,
            "value": "6,509"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 8469.38,
            "value": "8,469"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "name": "",
      "values": []
    },
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Interest",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": -85.44,
            "value": "(85)"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": -434.74,
            "value": "(435)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Interest Income",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0.57,
            "value": "1"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 1.24,
            "value": "1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Other Income",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 100,
            "value": "100"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Other Income and Expense",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": -84.87,
          "value": "(85)"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": -333.5,
          "value": "(334)"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Other Income and Expense"
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": true,
        "name": "Net Income  / (Loss) before Tax",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 6423.96,
            "value": "6,424"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 8135.88,
            "value": "8,136"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "name": "",
      "values": []
    },
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Net Income",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 6423.96,
            "value": "6,424"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 8135.88,
            "value": "8,136"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "name": "",
      "values": []
    },
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Total Comprehensive Income",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 6423.96,
            "value": "6,424"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 8135.88,
            "value": "8,136"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "name": "",
      "values": []
    },
    "title": ""
  }
]
```

https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Recommend c/p JSON into above link and selecting "tree viewer" to follow along with my navigation references

Problem:

**Snowflake/ASNI SQL:**

For each index in the array I need to evaluate a logical function that checks the "title" key, and if the value of the "title" key is X (for the sake of this exercise let's choose "Revenue"), return the "name" and "values" for each index of the "rows" key. Under rows:values you have 2 Values. They need to be re-keyed to MTD and YTD. They are consistently stored as [0]:MTD and [1]:YTD. I want these new keys to appear in a column I have named "periodicity." I know this is all one tricky flattening problem in snowflake, but I struggled with it all weekend in many different iterations and would like to see if someone can give it a shot. Thanks for the help!

Desired Output:
CID, TYPE, REPORT_DATE, "Title" Key, rows:Name as "Name", periodicity, rows:values:[0]:rawValue

EDIT: Sample output columns with values:

```
      CID    TYPE    REPORT_DATE    "Title" Key     rows:Name as "Name" 
       47    PNL      2020-01-01         REVENUE      "Sales - PayPal"

   periodicity       rows:values:[0]:rawValue
      "MTD"                        0
```

Comment: if your example json only has "one" block to care about "Revenue" can I suggest that you one need one other block that is not "Revenue" to demonstrate the mixed nature of the data. Also while you have described the names of the columns you want in the output, you have not put into your example the values you would expect to see for your example. Which would allow people to bridge the gap, between your describtion and you desired outcome.

Comment: Are you suggesting `prepared:profitAndLoss:report:sections` is the attached JSON, or literally the results of f.* is the JSON because the output of a f.* does not look like your JSON, which makes me wonder what you think your JSON is trying to represent.

Comment: Edited to show sample output, you nailed it thank you. The other blocks are in there under the other "title" keys so for example "title": "Operating Expenses". As for prepared:profitAndLoss:report:sections, no thats what I've been able to narrow the JSON down to from the original. The sample JSON is what's left to flatten.

Comment: so if the json has been flattened "correctly" is there any question left?

Comment: Nope! you got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the flatten is not too hard. If you take it step at a time:

```
with random_json as (
select '2020-05-27'::date as report_date, parse_json('[
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Product Sales",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 19889.16,
            "value": "19,889"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 56181.94,
            "value": "56,182"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Credits from Vendors",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 38,
            "value": "38"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 47.16,
            "value": "47"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Sales - PayPal",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 275,
            "value": "275"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Sales Returns and Allowances",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": -379.28,
            "value": "(379)"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": -941.78,
            "value": "(942)"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Revenue",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": 19547.88,
          "value": "19,548"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": 55562.32,
          "value": "55,562"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Revenue"
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Product Costs",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 9857.22,
            "value": "9,857"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 31907.32,
            "value": "31,907"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "emphasize": false,
        "name": "Supplies",
        "values": [
          {
            "rawValue": 0,
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "rawValue": 109.92,
            "value": "110"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "emphasize": false,
      "name": "Total Cost of Sales",
      "values": [
        {
          "rawValue": 9857.22,
          "value": "9,857"
        },
        {
          "rawValue": 32017.24,
          "value": "32,017"
        }
      ]
    },
    "title": "Less Cost of Sales"
  }
]') as json
), flatten_a AS (
select
        r.report_date
        ,f.value:rows as r_rows
        ,f.value:summary as r_summary
        ,f.value:title as r_title
    from random_json r
    ,lateral flatten(input=>r.json) f
), flatten_b AS (
select a.*
   , f.value:name as rr_name
   , f.value:values as rr_values
   from flatten_a a
   ,lateral flatten(input=>a.r_rows) f
)
select b.report_date
    ,b.r_title as title_key
    ,b.rr_name as name
    ,case when f.index =0 then 'MTD' when f.index=1 then 'YTD' else 'WTF' end as periodicity
    , f.value:rawValue raw_value
   from flatten_b b
   ,lateral flatten(input=>b.rr_values) f;
```

gives:

```
REPORT_DATE    TITLE_KEY              NAME                            PERIODICITY    RAW_VALUE
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Product Sales"                  MTD            19889.16
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Product Sales"                  YTD            56181.94
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Credits from Vendors"           MTD            38
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Credits from Vendors"           YTD            47.16
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Sales - PayPal"                 MTD            0
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Sales - PayPal"                 YTD            275
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Sales Returns and Allowances"   MTD            -379.28
2020-05-27    "Revenue"              "Sales Returns and Allowances"   YTD            -941.78
2020-05-27    "Less Cost of Sales"   "Product Costs"                  MTD            9857.22
2020-05-27    "Less Cost of Sales"   "Product Costs"                  YTD            31907.32
2020-05-27    "Less Cost of Sales"   "Supplies"                       MTD            0
2020-05-27    "Less Cost of Sales"   "Supplies"                       YTD            109.92
```

if what you mention in the first sentence as only wanting the above rows for "Revenue" make the results set a CTE also, and left join to your "report" and ON filter for revenue.